# C++ Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

Tags: compiler-errors

I know my problem lies within lines 25 and 30, I just can't seem to fix the issue.

I have tried declaring "Search" inside of the LinearInfo fuction and that didn't work. I have tried adding "const" inside of my declaration as well as leaving the "[AMOUNT]" spot on line 30 blank. Every time I change one thing I get thrown another error code. If anyone could help point me in the right direction as to what my options are in this situation, I'd greatly appreciate it! Side Note: I know my code will probably look messy to some but it is a class requirement that I follow along in my book and code how the class is and the last time I skipped ahead I was penalized for it so it has to be like it is for the most part. Thanks again in advance to any suggestions given.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//defining my variables
const int AMOUNT = 10;
int luckyNumbers[AMOUNT] = {13579, 26791, 26792, 33445, 55555, 62483, 77777, 79422, 85647, 93121};
int weeklyNumber;

//function that asks the user to enter the winning lottery number
int main()
{   
    cout << "Please enter this weeks winning lottery number." << endl;
    cin >> (weeklyNumber);

    cout << endl << endl << "The number you entered was: " << endl;
    cout << weeklyNumber;

return 0;   
}

//defining my prototype
    int Search(int[ ], int);

//beginning of function to assign the information for my linear search
int linearInfo()
{
    int winningNumber[] = {13579, 26791, 26792, 33445, 55555, 62483, 77777, 79422, 85647, 93121};

    //search the array for the users input
    winningNumber = Search(luckyNumbers[AMOUNT], weeklyNumber);

    //setting the result to false if the users input was not a lucky number
    if (winningNumber == -1)
    cout << "You did not win the lottery." << endl;

    //setting the result to true if the users input was one of the lucky numbers
    else
    {
        cout << "YOU WON THE LOTTERY!!" << endl <<endl;
    }
}

//beginning of fuction for the linear search
int winningNumber(const int arr[], int luckyNumbers, int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (index < luckyNumbers && !found)
    {
        if (arr[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;           
        }

        index++;
    }

    return position;
}
```

I am expecting this code to allow me to use a linear search to find out if the user's input for the weekly winning lottery number is inside the luckyNumbers list.

I am getting the error code "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'"and "initializing argument 1 of 'int Search(int*, int)'.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the first argument to `Search` as `int *` with `int Search(int [], int);`  You then try to call it with an `int` value -- `winningNumber[AMOUNT]` -- which is also an out-of-bounds array index (`AMOUNT` is 10 and the array only has 10 element with indexes 0..9).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I still am not able to get this code to work. I have been updating it for going on 48 hours now and can't get all the error codes to clear at once so it actually runs so I think I'm just going to ditch this code and start again from scratch. However, I really do appreciate you taking the time to respond with some insight!